# Theorem of Lidijski

Tags: operator-theory

I'm sorry this question is so "small".
My Operator Theory professor said we'd be proving The theorem of Lidijski next week. So I googled it and found nothing, and then i sort of panicked.

So that is my question:
Does anyone know this theorem of Lidijski he's talking about?

He has just finished proving the spectral theorem in the case of Banach and normed spaces.

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Lidskii.27s_theorem)? (Perhaps one of our Russian users can comment on the different spellings.)

Comment: This is correct. This is 99,9999% surely what he has in mid. Thank you very much. I'll prove this now.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is "theorem of Lidski" (search also "Lidskii" and "Lidskij").